# Is there a .NET library, which can emit .NET code for creating surrogate types?

Tags: .net

Observe the following code snippet:

```
  public class SomeType
  {
    public SomeType2 X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
  }

  public class SomeType2
  {
    public string Z { get; set; }
  }

  public class SomeTypeSurrogate
  {
    public static implicit operator SomeTypeSurrogate(SomeType obj) { return new SomeTypeSurrogate { X = obj.X, Y = obj.Y }; }
    public static implicit operator SomeType(SomeTypeSurrogate surrogate) { return new SomeType { X = surrogate.X, Y = surrogate.Y }; }
    public SomeType2Surrogate X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
  }

  public class SomeType2Surrogate
  {
    public static implicit operator SomeType2Surrogate(SomeType2 obj) { return new SomeType2Surrogate { Z = obj.Z }; }
    public static implicit operator SomeType2(SomeType2Surrogate surrogate) { return new SomeType2 { Z = surrogate.Z }; }
    public string Z { get; set; }
  }
```

My question is there a .NET library, which can generate the surrogate types like the ones in the example given the descriptions of the "real" types as well as the properties, that must be found in the surrogates?

For example, a fictional code could look like this (I am inspired by the RuntimeTypeModel from protobuf-net):

```
var model = new TypeSurrogateModel();
model.SetSurrogateNameScheme(SurrogateNameScheme.AddSuffix, "Surrogate");
model.AddType(typeof(SomeType), "X", "Y");
model.AddType(typeof(SomeType2), "Z");
model.Compile("Surrogates.dll");
...
var model = new TypeSurrogateModel();
model.AddAssembly("Surrogates.dll");
SomeType obj = GetSomeTypeInstance();
object surrogate = model.GetSurrogate(obj);
Debug.Assert(surrogate.GetType().Name == "SomeTypeSurrogate");
```

**OR**

Before building the assembly using the surrogates:

```
var model = new TypeSurrogateModel();
model.SetSurrogateNameScheme(SurrogateNameScheme.AddSuffix, "Surrogate");
model.AddType(typeof(SomeType), "X", "Y");
model.AddType(typeof(SomeType2), "Z");
model.GenerateSource("Surrogates.cs");
```

After Surrogates.cs is created and compiled, comes the turn of the assembly that uses it in a regular type safe manner:

```
SomeType obj = GetSomeTypeInstance();
SomeTypeSurrogate surrogate = obj;
```

Comment: Have you looked into an AOP library like PostSharp? I'm not sure if you can do something that involved but boilerplate code generation is AOP's raison d'être.

Comment: Yes, I did. In fact I use it. I do not see its benefit in this context. As I see it, I would still have to write pretty much everything.